# Jquery - Remove() after hide()

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a div that I want to remove using remove(). I want to show an animation before/while removal of div. I have only been able to show the animation when hiding the div.

If i want to show the animation then do remove(). How is this done???

Code so far:

```
//Delete Button - delete from cart
$('.ui-icon-trash').live('click',function() {
    $(this).closest('li').hide("puff", {}, 1000)
});
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Do it in the callback function for [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) (jQuery UI [`.hide()` reference](http://jqueryui.com/docs/hide/)), like this:

```
$('.ui-icon-trash').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('li').hide("puff", {}, 1000, function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

The function at the end runs as a callback, executing when the animation is done...so when you want :)

Comment: just as an update for those who come across this, live() is deprecated in the newest jQuery versions (as of 1.7)

Answer (score 6):

You might check this also:

```
$(this).hide("puff").delay(10).queue(function(){$(this).remove();});
```